# How can i save all the variable results from a echo into a txt file using php?

Tags: php

I wrote a php script that generates random tokens, and I want to output these tokens into a .txt file.

Below is the code:

```
do {

    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(2));

    echo("token: $token");

    $myfile = fopen("output.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $token);
    fclose($myfile);

} while ($token != "e3b0");
```

It echos multiple tokens, until the echo = e3b0, but when I try to write the result on a txt file, it only writes "e3b0", is that a way to write all the results of the "echo" into a txt file?

Comment: Do you only want to write to file, or do you also want it echo'd out to the browser/client?

Comment: And `while ($token != "e3b0")` is scary, as that has the potential to loop for a very long time at any random moment.

Comment: Replace `echo` with `file_put_contents`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat right now it only echos in the browser, im using xampp local server, on the browser it show all the generated tokens, i wanted this results to be saved in a txt file, about the loop, it doesnt really matter, im only using this for my self, so the "extra time" dont really bother me.

Comment: @user3783243 the file_put_contents does the same as the fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() right? if i replace the echo with it, this happen "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$myfile' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\random_bytes\index.php on line 14" i tried to remove fopen/fwrite/fclose, and replace it with file_put_contents and it still only show one token in the txt file

Comment: You need to use `append` constant, see manual.

Comment: im sorry, i dont understand how append would make it "print" more than one value into the txt file, as $token is generating different numbers in a loop, sorry but  i didnt really understand where/how i would use the append.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT: Efficiency was never asked in original OP question. This post is being edited to include efficiency, namely no need to reopen and close a file.

Your use of `w+` will always place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file in the process. So as a result, you always end up with the last value written.

From `php.net` on `fopen w+`:

```
Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file
and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
```

**Using your existing code**, a solution then would be as follows:

```
$myfile = fopen("output.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");

do {

    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(2));

    echo("token: $token");

    fwrite($myfile, $token);

} while ($token != "e3b0");

fclose($myfile);
```

Where `a+` in the same docs says:

```
Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. 
If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode, fseek() 
only affects the reading position, writes are always appended.
```

Source:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Amendments:

As @andreas mentions, opening and closing the file repeatedly inside the loop is not necessary (nor efficient). Since you are appending, you can open it once with `a+` before the loop begins; and close it after the loop ends.

In terms of having a separator char between tokens written to the file, a carriage return (line break) is a good choice. In this way you can reduce the amount of parsing you would have to program when programmatically reading the file. For this, your writes could be written as follows:

```
fwrite($myfile, $token . "\n");
```

Comment: So open and close the file on each iteration? Really?

Comment: thanks, it worked!how can i add any kind of "space" between each token? like a "-", it outputs all the values, but all together, as if it was a single value, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Andreas is there a more optimized way to do it?

Comment: @ChristopherCalson ***is there a more optimized way to do it?*** Yes see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As I see it the most efficient way to do this would be to do everything just enough times.
Meaning we have to loop and generate the codes, but we only need to write to the file once,same thing with the echo.

```
$code = "start value";
while ($code != "e3b0"){
    $arr[] = $code = bin2hex(random_bytes(2));
}

echo $str = implode("\n", $arr);
file_put_contents("output.txt", $str);
```

This is do everything just enough times, and a more optimized code.
But if you run this in a browser then it will not output them on separate lines on screen, only in the txt file. But if you open the source it will be on separate lines.
That is because I did not use the br tag in the implode.